# FFprobe details are almost identical, but some files don't play on TV or DVB-T2?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, tv

First file plays very well on both TV and DVB-T2.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.39.101
  Duration: 01:44:25.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 723 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 854x480 [SAR 1280:1281 DAR 16:9], 652 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Second file plays only on PC and Android Phone and don't play on TV or DVB-T2.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.39.101
  Duration: 01:30:59.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 721 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 854x480 [SAR 1280:1281 DAR 16:9], 650 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

There is some way to understand the reason?
Simply `ffmpeg -i file2.mp4 out.mp4` resolve problem, but this operation takes long (it is not a question of one file), so I wish to find other solution or at least find the reason.

---

**UPDATE:**
After check with MediaInfo I found the difference.
Problem video file (file2.mp4):

```
Writing library                          : x264 core 157
```

Good video file (file1.mp4):

```
Writing library                          : x264 core 161
```

Also video with `x264 core 159` plays without problem on my TV and DVB-T2. There is some problem with core 157 for some old devices maybe.